# Can this string searching algorithm be optimised?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, optimization

Recently I attempted a 'test' on a popular coding website which posed the question:

In a given string **s** find the substring of size **k** which contains the most vowels.

Example

**s = "eirowpfmsnaq*uisaa*"** and **k = 5** -

- Pass 1 - substring = "eirow" - Vowels = 3
- Pass 2 - substring = "irowp" - Vowels = 2
- Pass 3 - substring = "rowpf" - Vowels = 1
- Pass 4 - substring = "owpfm"  - Vowels = 1
- Pass 5 - substring = "wpfms" - Vowels = 0
- Pass 6 - substring = "pfmsn" - Vowels = 0
- Pass 7 - substring = "fmsna" - Vowels = 1
- Pass 8 - substring = "msnaq" - Vowels = 1
- Pass 9 - substring = "snaqu" - Vowels = 2
- Pass 10 - substring = "naqui" - Vowels = 3
- Pass 11 - substring = "aquis" - Vowels = 3
- Pass 12 - substring = "quisa" - Vowels = 3
- Pass 13 - substring = "uisaa" - Vowels = **4** (FINAL RESULT)

I created an initial trivial iterative function which simply iterated from 0 to the string length minus the length of the substring (**i=0 to i<s.length-k**)

```
const countVowels = str => str.length - str.replace((/[aeiouAEIOU]/gi), "").length

let findSubstring = (s,k) => {
  let max = 0, dict = {}
  for(let i=0;i<=s.length-k;i++) { // iterate over string length - k
    dict[i] = countVowels(s.slice(i, k+i)) // add vowels in substring to dict
    if(dict[i] > dict[max]) max = i // if there are more vowels than the max encountered this is the new max
  }
  return max === 0 ? "Not found!" : s.slice(max, max+k); // return substring if found
}
```

I found this method was successful for some test cases but it failed multiple on a 10 second timeout with larger inputs.

As a second attempt I decided removing the vowel counting out of the loop and using a map would be much quicker for the larger inputs. The first attempt would being quicker for smaller inputs due to the additional overhead in V2 to calculate the final result.

The second algorithm is as follows:

```
const countVowels = str => str.length - str.replace((/[aeiouAEIOU]/gi), "").length

let findSubstring = (s,k) => {
  let dict = {}, maxVowels, finalIndex
  for(let i=0;i<=s.length-k;i++) dict[i] = s.slice(i, k+i) // make dict of all substrings
  Object.values(dict).map((el, i) => dict[i] = countVowels(el)) // convert substring to vowel count
  maxVowels = Object.values(dict).sort((a, b) => a - b).pop() // sort to find max vowels
  finalIndex = parseInt(Object.keys(dict).find(key => dict[key] === maxVowels)) // search for first instance of string with max vowels
  return !finalIndex ? "Not found!" : s.slice(finalIndex, finalIndex+k) // return substring if found
}
```

*Interesting Note: The countVowels function uses .replace() over .match() as it affected the run time significantly with larger values, with smaller values being marginally better with .match()*

```
String of length 11628 with K=250. The results are an average over 5 runs

 .replace() - V1 = 66ms, V2 = 52ms
 .match() - V1 = 125ms, V2 = 92ms
```

As a comparison on smaller values such as the length of **s** less than 500 and **k** less than 100 V1 will outperform V2 9/10 times. However, once **s** has a length over 500 and *k* over 100 you can see V2 outperforming V1 with the performance margin growing as **s** and **k** get larger (as you would expect)

However, I found that when using V2 I was still having my tests failing due to the timeout. I can't see anything that can be changed in V2 which would optimise it significantly so I am curious to hear if anyone has any ideas that would make it quicker for large inputs.

Comment: Question question would better be served on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You don't have to completely re-examine all `k` elements of a substring each time you move forward. You have to count vowels at the beginning of the string, but each time you move forward you're going to change the number of vowels by -1, 0, or 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this would be much faster, it is just a single linear pass with O(1) lookups:

```
def count_vowels(s, k):
    vowels = set("aeiouAEIOU")

    #count first k
    t = sum(1 for i in s[:k] if i in vowels)
    mx = t
    for i in range(k, len(s)):
        if s[i] in vowels:
            t+=1
        if s[i-k] in vowels:
            t-=1
        if t > mx:
            mx = t

    return mx

count_vowels("eirowpfmsnaquisaaaa",5)
```

And here is how this can be implemented in JavaScript:

```js
function count_vowels(s, k) {
  const vowels = new Set(Array.from("aeiouAEIOU"));

  let t = 0;
  //count first k
  for (let i = 0; i < k && i < s.length; i++) {
    t += vowels.has(s[i]) ? 1 : 0;
  }

  let mx = t;

  for (let i = k; i < s.length; i++) {
    if (vowels.has(s[i])) {
      t += 1
    }
    if (vowels.has(s[i - k])) {
      t -= 1;
    }
    if (t > mx) {
      mx = t;
    }
  }

  return mx;
}

console.log(count_vowels("eirowpfmsnaquisaaaa", 5))
```

Comment: Well, this is Python code, not JavaScript I'd normally complain but this is it's simple enough to simply be used as pseudocode, so it's pretty useful as an answer even if one doesn't even run it.

Comment: You can just post that answer to help out OP. @VLAZ

Comment: Eh, I don't think it's necessary to have two answers about the same thing. Especially if mine is just going to be implementing your algorithm. I've added it to your answer as it belongs here. Also, turns out I was a dummy and did a couple of mistakes that I didn't notice because my implementation just happened to work with that sample string...I've removed the comment with the faulty implementations.

Comment: I appreciate the solution and can confirm this is much much quicker than the two solutions I had provided so I will accept it as the solution. I will add that the question required returning the substring itself although I can see that I didn't clarify this. Although it is clear that it only takes some trivial modifications to the provided answer to obtain the substring. Thanks again.

Comment: @Hydralore indeed - the modification should be to just keep track of `start` and `end` alongside `mx`. However, since you already know the length of the subsection (`k`) you can just keep one of `start` or `end` and then calculate the other as `+/- k`